# How to listen to a class signal globally?

Tags: c++, qt

Is it possible to listen to **any** `signal` emitted by a class without connecting **each** widget that this class is subclassing?

For example:

```
class Foo: public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:

    Foo(QWidget* parent = 0) : QWidget(parent) {}

signals:
    void test(int x);

};
```

---

Suppose i have **3** widgets being subclassed by `Foo`, to catch any `test` signal emitted by `Foo` i would need to write:

```
   connect(ui.widget_1, &Foo::test, [this](int x) { ... });    
   connect(ui.widget_2, &Foo::test, [this](int x) { ... });    
   connect(ui.widget_3, &Foo::test, [this](int x) { ... });
```

Is it somehow possible to listen to any signal emitted by `Foo` at once?

```
connect(/* ? */, &Foo::test, [this](int x) 
{ 
   // It would capture any test emitted by Foo independent from what widget.
});
```

Comment: are talking about having a separate class listen events emitted by other class, if this is the case then look into the Observer Pattern, https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/observer-pattern-set-1-introduction/

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no:  listening to a signal emitted from any object is not a feature that Qt provides.  Signal->slot connections are defined for a particular source and destination object only.

What you can do is create a function that connects up the signal(s) you want for a given object, and then call that function for each object you want to connect up:

```
void MyClass :: MakeMyConnections(QObject * source)
{
   connect(source, &Foo::test, [this](int) { ... });
   [... other connect() calls could go here....]
}

MyClass :: MyClass()
{
   [...]

   MakeMyConnections(ui.widget_1);
   MakeMyConnections(ui.widget_2);
   MakeMyConnections(ui.widget_3);
}
```

If you are subclassing `Foo()` you could go futher and put the signal-connection code similar to the above into your subclass's constructor, and then you wouldn't need to write a separate function call for each object.  (You'd probably need to pass in the destination `QObject *` as a constructor argument, since `this` would refer to the `Foo` object in that scenario)

In general, having your widgets accessible only as a group of individual member-variables (like `ui.widget_1`, `ui.widget_2`, `ui.widget_3`) is a code-maintenance headache, since any time you want to do any operation to all of the widgets you have to write separate code for each of them.  If you're planning to do operations on all of the widgets, probably the first thing you should do is add all of the widget-pointers into a data structure (e.g. a `std::vector<QWidget *>` or a `QList<QWidget *>` or whatever), so that you can then just iterate over the list whenever you need to perform the same calls on every widget.